# Обновить сразу несколько данных в БД из другой таблицы

Tags: php, sql

Есть две таблицы, из одной таблицы хочу взять данные и обновить в другой по ID, но не пойму как это сделать одной кнопкой или без.

```html
<?
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/safemysql.class.php';
$db = new safeMysql();

$sql1  = "SELECT products.id, px_items_link_cars.id_items, GROUP_CONCAT(px_items_link_cars.id_body SEPARATOR ',') as pxbody FROM products
INNER JOIN px_items_link_cars
on products.id = px_items_link_cars.id_items
GROUP BY products.id";

$data1 = $db->getAll($sql1);

  
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $spec = $_POST['spec'];

  $db->query("UPDATE products SET specifications=?s WHERE id=?i", $spec, $id);

}

?>

<? foreach ($data1 as $row1): ?>

<form action="" method="post">

  <input name="id" type="text" value="<?=$row1['id']?>"><input name="spec" type="text" value='{"id_cars_body":[<?=$row1['pxbody']?>]}' />

  <button name="btns" type="submit">Кнопка</button>

</form>

<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: а обязательно обновлять сразу несколько? Я предлагаю обновлять по одной. Так код получится проще и и у тебя получится его освоить самостоятельно

Comment: @Ипатьев там > 1500 записей, которые нужно обновить.

Comment: я понимаю. но можно же обновлять по одной. одну запись отредактировал - отправил на сервер, вторую отредактировал - отправил. по одной

Comment: но если вот прям невмоготу хочется обновлять сразу все, то `<input name="spec[<?=$row1['id']?>]" type="text" value='{"id_cars_body":[<?=$row1['pxbody']?>]}' />` и потом перебирать `foreach($_POST['spec'] as $id=> $spec)`

Comment: хотя конечно за хранение джейсона в БД, да еще и редактирование его руками,  я бы руки-то оторвал

Comment: стоп. или редактировать ничего не надо а надо только пропадейтить спецификации? а зачем форма тогда?

Comment: @Ипатьев данные в первой таблице храняться, как обычные строки по отдельности(не в json) и мне нужно их обновить, но уже в json для другой таблицы .

Comment: обновить **с редактированием или без?**

Comment: и это неправильный способ хранения. в бд для хранения списков служат таблицы, когда каждый элемент лежит в своей ячейке, а не все запихиваются в одну

Comment: @Ипатьев ну новые какие то значение редактировать не нужно, просто, перед обновлением, из вида первой таблицы id 1 = 2 , id 1 = 4 ... перевести в {"id_cars_body":[2, 4]} и обновить существующую запись.

Comment: **а зачем форма-то тогда, если редактировать не нужно?!**

Comment: если редактировать не нужно то тогда таблица specifications просто бессмысленная. джейсон можно получить сразу тем же запросом

Comment: никак. это бессмысленный код, который переливает из пустого в порожнее. таблицу specifications выкинуть на помойку, те данные которые в ней лежат, получать из первого запроса по необходимости